# Pattern Matching on Either

Tags: scala, either

From [Functional Programming in Scala](http://www.manning.com/bjarnason/), I'm trying to implement `Either.map`.

```
trait Either[+E, +A] {
    def map[B](f: A => B): Either[E, B] =  this match {
        case Either(x: E, y: A) => Right(f(y))
        case _ => Left()
    }
}
```

One error shows up on compilation, among others. I'm not showing them since I appear to be missing the concept of implementing `Either.`

```
    Either.scala:3: error: value Either is not a case class constructor, 
nor does it have an unapply/unapplySeq method
                    case Either(x: E, y: A) => Right(f(y))
```

Please advise me on implementing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message says that you cannot use `Either` as a case class constructor. IOW, `Either` is equivalent to an abstract class since you have encoded it as a trait with its own implementable methods. Let's assume you have the following encoded representation of `Either`, `Left` and `Right`:

```
sealed trait Either[+E, +A] {
    def map[B](f: A => B): Either[E, B] =  ???
}

// Left signifies error condition
// Right is something Right, along with its message.
case class Left[+E](err: E) extends Either[E,Nothing]
case class Right[+E](msg: E) extends Either[Nothing,E]
```

You can write the `map` function as:

```
def map[B](f: A => B): Either[E, B] = this match {
    case Right(v) => Right(f(v))
    case Left(e) => Left(e)
}
```

Here I'm simply saying that if you encounter something that's supposed to be a right value, perform some function computation on it and return it exactly as it should be - a `Right`. Since `Either` is a `sealed trait`(mainly for convenience), the only other type could be a `Left` which I return as is. [Read more about `Either`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/Either.html)

Answer (score 3):

try this one

```
trait Either[+E, +A] {
    def map[B](f: A => B): Either[E, B] =  this match {
        case Right(y) => Right(f(y))
        case left: Left[E] => left
    }
}
```

Comment: 4 compile-time errors on v. 2.10.2: (1) error: constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type; (2) error: not found: value y; (3) error: wrong number of type arguments for Left, should be 2; (4)  type mismatch;

Comment: Then post full sources with `Left` and `Right` definitions

Comment: Hey @1esha, after I added the case classes from "S.R.I"'s post, your code compiled for me. Thanks.